# How to handle minus operator with SOCI library?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, postgresql, soci

I need to use SOCI library to handle minus operator in a database agnostic way.
Oracle keyword 'MINUS' does not support in postgres and respective postgres keyword is 'EXCEPT' .
Ex : Oracle Syntax
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT C1 FROM s1.T1 **MINUS** (SELECT C1 FROM S2.T1));`

Postgres Syntax
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT C1 FROM s1.T1 **EXCEPT** (SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM C1 FROM s2.T1));`

Likewise SOCI library provide a function to handle nvl ('''soci::session::nvl()'''), is there any capability to handle minus operator as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SOCI library has provided a function call soci::session::except() function to fulfill this requirement.